# What's __int32?

Tags: c#, c++, c, pinvoke

I've been trying to understand [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc249651.aspx). It's a reference page for a structure called `W32TIME_STATUS_INFO`.

```
 typedef struct {
   unsigned __int32 ulSize;
   unsigned __int32 eLeapIndicator;
   unsigned __int32 nStratum;
   signed __int32 nPollInterval;
   unsigned __int32 refidSource;
   unsigned __int64 qwLastSyncTicks;
   signed __int64 toRootDelay;
   unsigned __int64 tpRootDispersion;
   signed __int32 nClockPrecision;
   [string, unique] wchar_t* wszSource;
   signed __int64 toSysPhaseOffset;
   unsigned __int32 ulLcState;
   unsigned __int32 ulTSFlags;
   unsigned __int32 ulClockRate;
   unsigned __int32 ulNetlogonServiceBits;
   unsigned __int32 eLastSyncResult;
   unsigned __int64 tpTimeLastGoodSync;
   unsigned __int32 cEntries;
   [size_is(cEntries)] PW32TIME_ENTRY pEntries;
 } W32TIME_STATUS_INFO,
  *PW32TIME_STATUS_INFO;
```

I'd like to use the method `W32TimeQueryStatus` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc249691.aspx) in C# code but I don't know how I should define the structure in C# code and the method takes a pointer to it as an argument. What are all of these `__int32` and `__int64` things? I've searched for "double underscore c" and such but everything I'm finding is very non-specific.

I'll probably have to ask about the `handle_t` argument separately so for now I'd just like to ask about defining this structure and passing it to a PInvoked method in C#.

Comment: It's a signed integer data type guaranteed to 32 bits long.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dh1w7z.aspx

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks, so I should just use `Int32` in C# code?

Comment: Int32 and Int64 respectively - and handle will be IntPtr (or UIntPtr): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Use [google](https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=__int64) and first link [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/29dh1w7z.aspx) says:

> Microsoft C/C++ features support for sized integer types. You can
>   declare 8-, 16-, 32-, or 64-bit integer variables by using the __intn
>   type specifier, where n is 8, 16, 32, or 64.

And as you can see on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wf2yk2k.aspx) c# equivalent is `System.Int64`

Answer (score 2):

Extract from the 2003 C++ Standard:

> Each name that contains a double underscore (_ _) or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.11) is reserved to the implementation for any use.

To simplify, `__int32` is an `int` coded on 32 bits and `__int64` on 64. You eliminate the size abstraction of the standard `int` type, with this you're certain that the variable will allocate 4 bytes precisely

Answer (score 0):

Replace "unsigned __int32" with "Uint32" and for signed __int32 use "Int32". Same goes for __int64.

Answer (score 0):

As other have said `signed __int32` is a 32-bit 2's complement integer and `unsigned __int32` is a 32-bit unsigned integer.

Using `__` before `int32` to form `__int32` makes it a **reserved** identifier.  An important advantage to this is that it will **not collide** with compliant pre-existing user code.

Use like below encourages compiler dependency

```
unsigned __int32 ulSize;
```

Better to use the following.  Even if `<stdint.h>` is not supplied for your compiler, on-line ones exist for it.

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint32_t ulSize;
```